# Start postgresql in boot on Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: postgresql, boot, ubuntu-10.04

I installed Postgresql 8.4 from Ubuntu Software Center. I would like to make it start automatically on boot. Any tips? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update-rc.d postgresql-8.4 defaults`

Make sure you read [update-rc.d(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/update-rc.d.8.html).

Comment: When I tried using this and it said postgresql is already supposed to start at boot. When viewing log files I noticed that there was error and that's why it doesn't start on boot. Still good to know this command if I need to setup other services to start at boot.